# How to add a checkbox beside the rows in datatable to be able to select each row

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, wpfdatagrid

I use the SqlCeDataAdapter to fill the table data. But after that I want to add checkboxes for users to select certain rows, then get the list of the primary keys and do certain operations. I can't seem to figure out how to do it

I'm using windows forms (WPF) and I'm using DataGridView to display the DataTable. .NetFramework 4.0

Comment: That datatable is Datagridview C# or Gridview Asp.net ??

Comment: @BuiAkinori It is a Datagridview that I use it, in C#. I'm using WPF

Comment: @Damith Sorry, it is windows forms in C# (WPF) and putting the table in a datagridview

Comment: I take it you're not following the MVVM pattern? Working with a DataTable I think you'll have to to add a boolean column to the DataTable to represent a *select* state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as easy as adding a new Column object to the datatable.columns collection